# Why does Docker fail to open nginx.conf when I try to mount a volume?

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm on OS X. First, I used `docker pull nginx` to get the official image from Docker hub. Next, I created a folder on my host and I'm trying to map (not sure what the correct vernacular is) the nginx configuration directory to my host. So, I tried this.

```
docker run -p 80:80 --rm -v /Users/me/helloworld/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/ nginx
```

However, that command results in this.

```
2015/05/08 23:42:47 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I checked inside of the container and I can confirm that file exists.

Comment: Is there a `nginx.conf` in `/Users/me/helloworld/nginx/conf`? Does `/Users/me/helloworld/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` exists on your OS X host?

Comment: `/Users/me/helloworld/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` does not exist. OMG. Is that the problem?

Comment: Oh, snap. You're right! I'm doing this wrong. I thought files would come *from* the container *to* the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NGiNX in the container looks for `nginx.conf` when starting.

That means you need `/Users/me/helloworld/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` in order for the mounted volume to give the right file at the right place.

> How to grab a copy of the configuration files in the container?

You can run it *without mounting* any host folder:

```
docker run --rm -it nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Can't accept answer yet because of time limit. In the meantime, maybe this should be a separate post but: how could I grab a copy of the configuration files in the container? That way I can have somewhere to start my nginx configuration.

Comment: Do you maybe need an `-` in the command?
Should it maybe be:
`docker run --rm -it nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
?

Comment: @A_C Right! I have edited the answer accordingly. Thank you.